# How can I get data from JDBC + Java to Javascript with Vert.x?

Tags: java, javascript, jdbc, vert.x

I'm a noob with vertx, but I have already created the JDBC connection manager using a java class where I can print data from the result set:

```
ConnectionManager cm=ConnectionManager.getInstance();
Connection conn = cm.getConnection();
try {
    Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
    try {
        ResultSet rs =
        stmt.executeQuery("select username, password from users");              
        try {
            if (rs.next()){
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
            }
        } finally {
            rs.close();
        }

    } finally {
        stmt.close();
    }

} finally {
    conn.close();
}
```

Now I want to connect my vertx javascript app to this java class. I can't seem to get an idea where to start. I found a few sources from Google Groups, but none of them seem to shed some light:

**Loading JDBC Drivers from JavaScript**
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/vertx/_oJQaeH07Sg

**Executing Java from Javascript**
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/vertx/VyZj2yqqGTM/tvnTg4T55kMJ

I've also found a jdbc-persistor for Vert.x:

**JDBC-persistor**
https://github.com/timyates/mod-jdbc-persistor/

I'm still trying to understand how to use it with my app. I will post whatever information I can share after, but for now, can anyone help me with this (persistor or direct java communication)? Thanks.

Comment: How about sending the data to a javascript vertical with json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK the only way to do it is using the event bus.
You put your Java code in a Verticle class (or in alternative create a module just for the goal). Something like this

```
public class JavaFromEverywhere extends Verticle {

    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {
        vertx.eventBus().registerHandler("invokeFromAnyLanguage", new Handler<Message<String>>(){
            public void handle(Message<String> e) {
                doSomething();
            }

        });
    }

    private void doSomething() {
        // your database code here
    }

}
```

Then in your javascript you should just write

```
vertx.eventBus.send("invokeFromAnyLanguage", "");
```

This is a simple scenario. If you want do more complex things like sending to your JS the String received from the DB you can extend `BusModBase` and send back data. Meanwhile in your JS you should register an handler to handle the reply

```
public class JavaReply extends BusModBase {

    @Override
    public void start() {
        eb.registerHandler("invokeFromAnyLanguage", new Handler<Message<String>>(){
            public void handle(Message<String> e) {
                String something = doSomething();
                e.reply(something);
            }                
        });           
    }

    private String doSomething() {
        // your database code here
        return "databaseResult";
    }

}
```

and your JS code would be something like

```
eb.send("invokeFromAnyLanguage", "", function(javareply) {
    // your answer in javareply
});
```

HTH, Regards

Carlo